# Can I connect to Oracle database without Oracle JDBC driver?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

TL;DR:

Is there a way to connect to an Oracle DB via JDBC without the Oracle JDBC driver? Or any other way (e.g. hibernate)?

Full story:

We have an existing Spring Boot app, which connects to an Oracle 11c database instance using OJDBC driver. Spring Boot internally uses JdbcTemplate to execute a few inserts and selects, basically 5 or 6 type of statements. Technically it is working fine.

However we are in an interesting situation, the code we built has to pass through a series of checks (we are working as subcontractors under a larger international company), and part of these checks is a license inspection. BlackDuck (https://www.blackducksoftware.com) is used to report every single library which is linked in the solution (around 280 in our case), and we had to manually add the copyright statement to each (for example: "Copyright © 2005-2019 The Apache Software Foundation. All Rights Reserved."). We added the Oracle Technology Network license to the Oracle Driver, and it was rejected by the legal team of the international company:

*"Unless we are actually licensed to use an Oracle database (which you are not), we cannot allow the use and distribution of the Oracle JDBC drivers. Those drivers are licensed under the Oracle Technology network license and it obligates XXX [company name] to designate Oracle as a 3rd party beneficiary, which is not something our legal department allows.  You must therefore find a compatible replacement that is licensed under open source."*

Now, we are obviously trying to get around this thing (seeing as the end client who is receiving the solution has a licensed Oracle DB installed, and we can see earlier versions of the OJDBC driver in the company's Nexus repository), but I wanted to ask, is there a way to connect to an Oracle DB via JDBC without the Oracle JDBC driver? Or any other way (e.g. hibernate)? To my knowledge, Oracle DB communication protocol is not fully standard, that's why you need the Oracle drivers. Is there an open source alternative that I don't know of?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle DB communication protocol is not only "not fully standard", there is simply no SQL or JDBC standard for any on-the-wire communication protocol for SQL databases, they are all proprietary.

There is no open-source alternative that I'm aware of, and there couldn't be without Oracle's help as the protocol is not publicly specified as far as I know. We solved a similar problem by having our customers with an Oracle license add the driver to their deployment of our app, that way we didn't redistribute it, and they were the ones who used it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought. I'll try to find some articles on this topic, and present it to the legal team. We were thinking of a similar solution, basically we mark the OJDBC driver in pom.xml as "provided", so that it is not distributed with the app.

Comment: Oracle JDBC drivers are available on Central Maven (https://medium.com/@kuassimensah). The pom file does include the required FUTC license. So, you can use the 19.3 JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use someone else's driver. [Progress](https://www.progress.com/blogs/distributing-the-oracle-thin-jdbc-driver) makes one for example.

I'm not speaking on behalf of Oracle in terms of the quality of THIS driver or the legal terms concerning your decision to not use our driver. However, there are alternatives to our driver for Java applications, and this is one of them.